# CSS apply padding only if slot is empty?

Tags: css, web-component

I'm making a webcomponent that optionally allows for elements to be put before or after an input (such as an icon) using slots.

```
class Input extends FormElement {

  static template = `
    <slot name='before'></slot>
    <input part=input />
    <slot name='after'></slot>
    <slot></slot>
  `;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = Input.template;
  }
}
```

I want to control the padding of the input based on if there is anything in the slots. I'd rather the slotted elements control their padding instead of the web component forcing it.

I've tried to use the css `slot:empty` but this appears to always be the case. Even with something added to the slot, my padding is still getting applied.

```
slot[name="after"]:empty {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in only CSS? I'm guessing this is due to the element actually being in the light DOM so the slot really is empty.

I cant use :empty on the parent either because I have two slots. One could be filled while the other empty.

```
<zy-input-new>
  <ion-icon slot=after name="analytics-outline"
</zy-input-new>
```

[image]

Comment: With given code CSS rules are not applied to `<slot name="after">Foo</span>`, so your code works as intended.

Comment: How is your icon applied to the slot - ::before/::after element with generated content? :empty still applies to an element that has nothing but those.

Comment: I've updated my question. While yes, it does work if you add something in the template for the slot, thats not the case for elements added from the light dom? (AKA creating an instance of the web component and adding elements to it)

Comment: I'd also do not want to require manually set the padding, such as setting a pad-left or pad-right class on the web component itself.

Answer (score 0):

One potential answer I've come up with is always having the padding on my web component. Then using first-of-type and last-of-type setting a negative margin to remove the padding. Negative margins always feel hacky though so I'm curious if there's any other solutions.

```
zy-input-new {
  --padding: 15px;
  padding: 0 var(--padding);
}

zy-input-new [slot="after"]:last-of-type {
  margin-right: calc(var(--padding) * -1);
}

zy-input-new [slot="before"]:first-of-type {
  margin-left: calc(var(--padding) * -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding HTML to your template, you can put a "padding" element into each slot as the fallback content:

```
<slot name="before">
    <div class="padding"></div>
</slot>
<input part="input">
<slot name="after">
    <div class="padding"></div>
</slot>
```

And then add the style for that class:

```
.padding {
   width: 15px;
}
```